# Send 2 different size of images to FB OG tags

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

As I'm adding new writers to my editorial project - most of whom never worked with featured images before - I'm trying to build a more streamlined way to handle pictures when sharing content to FB. I've used several plug-ins in the past but that always yielded unsatisfactory results, one way or another. Now, I finally decided to code the whole thing myself.

I scoured the net for info and found a few pretty solid articles on defining default Open Graph properties in your theme. The code contained in this piece from [wp-beginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-in-wordpress-themes/) might be a solid one to start from, although it'll need editing to suit my needs.

```
//Adding the Open Graph in the Language Attributes
function add_opengraph_doctype( $output ) {
        return $output . ' xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"';
    }
add_filter('language_attributes', 'add_opengraph_doctype');

//Lets add Open Graph Meta Info

function insert_fb_in_head() {
    global $post;
    if ( !is_singular()) //if it is not a post or a page
        return;
        echo '<meta property="fb:admins" content="YOUR USER ID"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_the_title() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="Your Site NAME Goes HERE"/>';
    if(!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) { //the post does not have featured image, use a default image
        $default_image="http://example.com/image.jpg"; //replace this with a default image on your server or an image in your media library
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
    }
    else{
        $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>';
    }
    echo "
";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );
```

The problem, however, is that everything I found only discussed using a single image size.

At this point, I'm at a bit of a loss. Cropping the picture isn't a problem, but is there a way to tell FB to use two different images, one for rectangular banners (the ones used in pages - just to be clear) and one for squared thumbnails (the chat/comment ones), so as to avoid having a badly cropped image in one case or the other?

In layman's terms: I'm looking for a way to pass two independent images to FB through the OG protocol (I might want to create a form later on so that the authors can simply paste the links, but that's a thing for the future). The solution I'm looking for should also ensure that FB understands which image is meant for thumbnails and which one should instead be used for banners.

Comment: Please include the code you tried in the question, so others can help better.

Comment: Code has been added! As I said, it'll need some editing in order to work for my project, but I feel that's a good way to start putting things together.